# Trying to raise ' n' to increments of n**2 - in a certain range

Tags: range, double, increment

PYTHON

I think this is rather a simple question,,
I wish to raise the 'n' to the increments of n^2 from (n = 2~1000)
so that n would be 2, 4, 9,16 .... 1000^

starting with something like this?
Thank you

```
for n in range(2,1000___ ):
```

Comment: Is this about a particular programming language?

Comment: What is the problem you are struggling with and in which language do you try to implement your results?

Comment: oh I am so sorry - python. I am trying to do something like this : for f(x), I wish to get results for f(2),f(4),f(9).. f(n^2) ..f(1000^2)